# User To Select Variable For Access SQL Code

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Creating a query that analyzes what is needed to produce throughout the entire plant off of the finished good forecast. The monthly demand is pulled in but trying to figure out how to easily choose the month to look at as they are separate columns.

The below SQL is what I currently have and I want to DIM a variable from a user input to select the number(Month) that are bolded.   Ex. User inputs "4" and it changes to [MPS Customer Forecast]![4]. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
SELECT [MPS Customer Forecast]![Part] AS [Finished Good]
, [MPSCustomer Forecast].Part
, ***[MPS Customer Forecast]![3]*** AS [MonthDemand]
, BOMs.[Component No]
, BOMs.[Component Name]
, BOMs.[BOMQuantity]
, ([BOMs]![BOM Quantity][MPS Customer Forecast]![3]***) AS [Comp Month Dem]
, [Active Routings - Primary].[Approved WorkcenterRates]
,[MPS Customer Forecast]![3][BOMs]![BOM Quantity]/[Active
Routings - Primary]![Approved Workcenter Rates] AS [Needed Hours]
,[Active Routings - Primary].[Workcenter Code]
```

Comment: `Dim`is VBA but I don't see any VBA. Also, I don't see a complete SQL statement. So where does this query sit? In a VBA procedure? Is it meant to be a saved query in the database? It seems that `[MPS Customer Forecast]` is something like a crosstab query, so I suggest not to do this. Use the calculation from the crosstab query instead and filter by month.

Comment: Hi WolfgangK. Yes it is in a saved query in the database. Here is a simplified Access SQL to highlight what I'm looking at. Where there is the "..Forecast]![3]" is where I'd like to be able to input a variable. As the demand for each month are their own field so I can't select criteria that way................................. SELECT [MPS Customer Forecast].Part, [MPS Customer Forecast]![2] AS [Month Demand] FROM [MPS Customer Forecast];

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You can't pass a parameter to the query to decide what columns to return.

If you can't access the underlying records that were used to calculate the values for the 12 months, I see two opportunities to achieve what you want:

**1. Use a UNION query**

Instead of querying the table `[MPS Customer Forecast]`, query a query that is defined as a UNION query (`[MPS Customer Forecast UNION]`) like so (add more fields if required):

```
SELECT 1 AS [Month], [1] AS [MonthDemand], [Part] FROM [MPS Customer Forecast]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS [Month], [2] AS [MonthDemand], [Part] FROM [MPS Customer Forecast]
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 12 AS [Month], [12] AS [MonthDemand], [Part] FROM [MPS Customer Forecast]
```

The main query the could look like this (you forgot an arithmetic operator between `MonthDemand` and `BOMQuantity`, so did I):

```
PARAMETERS MonthParameter Short;
SELECT [MPS Customer Forecast UNION]![Part] AS [Finished Good]
, [MPS Customer Forecast UNION].Part
, [MPS Customer Forecast UNION].[MonthDemand]
, BOMs.[Component No]
, BOMs.[Component Name]
, BOMs.[BOMQuantity]
, ([BOMs]![BOM Quantity][MPS Customer Forecast UNION]![MonthDemand]) AS [Comp Month Dem]
, [Active Routings - Primary].[Approved WorkcenterRates]
,[MPS Customer Forecast UNION].[MonthDemand][BOMs]![BOM Quantity]/[Active
Routings - Primary]![Approved Workcenter Rates] AS [Needed Hours]
,[Active Routings - Primary].[Workcenter Code]
...
WHERE ((([MPS Customer Forecast UNION].[Month]) = [MonthParameter]))
```

**2. Use the `Choose` function to choose one of the 12 values:**

Instead of accessing a month-related column, choose the value according to the parameter of the query:

```
PARAMETERS MonthParameter Short;
...
Choose([MonthParameter], [MPS Customer Forecast]![1], [MPS Customer Forecast]![2], [MPS Customer Forecast]![3], [MPS Customer Forecast]![4], [MPS Customer Forecast]![5], [MPS Customer Forecast]![6], [MPS Customer Forecast]![7], [MPS Customer Forecast]![8], [MPS Customer Forecast]![9], [MPS Customer Forecast]![10], [MPS Customer Forecast]![11], [MPS Customer Forecast]![12])
...
```